# HTML/CSS label left goes past div

Tags: html, css

Why is my label going past the div-width when I add left:x to the label?

```css
.TheDiv {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.TheLabel {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="TheDiv">
  <label class="TheLabel">See this label is going past the div</label><br>
  <label class="TheLabel">See this label is going past the div</label>
</div>
```

Comment: because of width:200px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the child is still taking the parent's width as you're not using absolute positioning correctly. The parent should have `position: relative` and the child should have `position: absolute` for this to work.

Here's your code after applying this:

```css
.TheDiv {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative; /* Added this*/
}

.TheLabel {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute; /* Changed this*/
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="TheDiv">
  <label class="TheLabel">See this label is going past the div</label>
</div>
```

---

If you want to keep the `position: relative` on the children to make them stack over one another automatically, then display them as `block`s and limit their `width`, like so:

```css
.TheDiv {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.TheLabel {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;

  /* Add this part */
  display: block;
  width: 170px; /* parent's width - child's left*/
  margin-bottom: 2px; /* instead of <br> */
}
```

```html
<div class="TheDiv">
  <label class="TheLabel">See this label is going past the div</label>
  <label class="TheLabel">See this label is going past the div</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my updated code, using absolute here will cause the two labels to overlap each other. And I don't want to use top:x as a way to fix this problem (because 20 labels later top:x is a nightmare)

Comment: @Frank I updated my answer, you beat me to it though :)

Comment: Bhahaha all good man! Thanks for your answer though. I'll mark yours as the answer since you have some more info anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I found for my case. Adding display:block and a width:x to the label.

```css
.TheDiv {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.TheLabel {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="TheDiv">
  <label class="TheLabel">See this label is going past the div</label><br>
  <label class="TheLabel">See this label is going past the div</label>
</div>
```